# Domain of the biggest value for $abcd\dots$ given $a+b+c+d\cdots=10$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, puzzle, domain-theory

I've seen this puzzle on Flammable Maths new video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW4TjU4IoPY)(optional to watch). It is as follows:

"Given a+b+c+d+e...=10, what is the biggest value for a*b*c*d*e... given n elements?"

I've managed to do my own solution using calculus, here it is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sSQN_OQCtTzafJnkSPGT7XK28QdamF2XlLDLTxLFVA0/edit?usp=sharing

Thing is, I'm accidentally only accounting for positive values of a, b, c.... If I weren't, the set (500, -489, -1), for example, would be a solution to a + b + c = 10. So it's clear negative numbers allow for infinitely large products. On my solution, I didn't consciously restrict the domain for positive numbers at all, and yet only got the positive solution. I'm wondering what step did I take that restricted my domain.

I've found the same exact solution as the one in the video, in which its assumed (a, b, c, d, e...) are all positive. The only explanation I can think to explain this is that I've accidentaly totally disregarded a set of solutions, through some operation with restricted domain, of which I don't know. So, the main question here is "Where, did on my solution, I accidentally restricted the domain of my solutions?"

Both links I posted offer different ways to find the biggest value for a*b*c*d..., and the purpose of this post isn't to find the best solution, but to understand a possible neglect I've done on my solution regarding the domain range.

Comment: Try to post a question as self-contained a possible.

Comment: You never restricted the domain of your solutions. When you set the derivatives to zero and solve, you are finding all _local_ maxima and minima. Yes, there are better solutions when you allow variables to be negative, but none of these are _locally_ maximal. For example, the solution $(500,-499,-1)$ is improved by changing it to $(500+d,-499-d,-1)$, for any number $d>0$.

Comment: Yes, we shouldn't need to watch a video to understand the question.

Comment: About keeping the question self-contained, I thought it'd be nice to credit the channel for this puzzle, as it offers a second solution that some might be interested to give a look at. It's not really necessary to watch the video, as I have specified the problem in the google docs posted, and said in the second paragraph the video is an alternative solution. However, I'll be more careful about this when posting further questions, as I am a new user here.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for your answer, makes perfect sense to me now.

Comment: Sorry, but the Google doc is also an external document. Ask the question here. @Marvin

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've reformulated my post. The only part not contained now is my solution, which I thought to be too big/distracting to show while contextualizing the problem. I hope this post better suited now.